# import data from excel to a model django

Tags: python, django-models

Hi All I am trying to import a data from an excel sheet to the models in Django.

I have a little snippet to parse the data in the excel sheet and a 'mapping' that maps my models to the excel header names.

```
keys = [sheets.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheets.ncols)]
dict_list = []
for row_index in xrange(1,sheets.nrows):
d_list = {
        keys[col_index]:sheets.cell(row_index,col_index).value
        for col_index  in xrange(sheets.ncols)
         }

print d_list
dict_list.append(d_list)

print dict_list
for every_row in dict_list:
 print every_row['name']
```

```
mapping={'address.name' :['NAME', 'name',],
         'address.street':['street','way'],
         'study.description':['education','degree'],
         .....'
}
```

Now I have to build a dictionary to map column headers/numbers from the excel sheet to the models/fields with the mappings dictionary and first line of the given excel sheet. how should I incorporate the mappings dict in my snippet of parsing the excel. Any help would be much appreciated. PS. I Am  new to python and django so if you see any absurd terms/ coding practice please correct me. Thanks

I need to achieve something like this :

```
dict_mapping={0:'address.name',
              1:'address.street',
              2:'some models.field',
              3:'model.field',


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your dictionary in a way that maps your fieldnames to the values you extract.
Then use something like models.objects.create(**mydict_mapping)